# Application/script for merging images, applying color, black & white filter in batch?

Tags: image, image-manipulation, image-editing

I'm making achievements for my game, and I would like to make an automated process to save a lot of time instead of doing it manually. (I'm using Windows)

The **inputs** of this process would be

- **one** rectangular opaque background image (i.e. 200x200 PNG)
- Color A, (i.e. in hex)
- Color B, (i.e. in hex)
- and **multiple** same sized, rectangular, transparent foreground images. (i.e. 200x200 PNG)

And the **process** would do this for **every foreground image**:

1. **Start with the background** image.
2. Merge the foreground image with **Color A filter** applied, and also with **an offset from the middle**.
3. Merge the foreground image with **Color B filter** applied, in the **middle**.
4. **Save the result in a file**.
5. Apply a **black & white filter** and **save the result in a file**.

So the output would be for example multiple 200x200 PNG images, each of it having a colored and a black & white version

I think there must be an **application** capable of this.

But if not, is there a way to quickly do this in some **programming/script language** for example in Python?

Comment: We're missing some details... representative input images, colours (and how they are specified), the expected corresponding output image, some idea of what language and operating system you use, how many images you have, what you consider fast enough. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, now I've updated it, hopefully it's a bit more clear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best you can hope for without providing any images or expected results. I am using the following as background, image A and image B:

[image] [image] [image]

Then using **ImageMagick**, like this:

```
magick background.png -gravity center \
   \( a.png -fill "#ff00ff" -tint 70% -resize 64x64   -geometry -30-40 \) -composite \
   \( b.png -fill "#00ff00" -tint 85% -resize 100x100 -geometry +0+0   \) -composite \
   -write coloured.png \
   -colorspace gray grey.png
```

You'll get:

[image] [image]

If using Windows, you'll need to:

- replace any `\` at end of line with caret `^`
- remove any `\` before opening and closing parentheses `(` and `)`
- change any single quotes to double quotes
- mess around with any `%` signs using some arcane Microsoft rules about doubling them up to make sure it really does what you asked it in batch files.

Comment: This seems exactly what I needed, I will try it out after work :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi! It works well with colored images, but for example if I try to use this: "magick input.png -fill "#ff00ff" -tint 70% output.png" on an image which is a white symbol on a transparent background... then it stays white. Why?

Comment: Please share your image so I can work it out. Thank you.

Comment: Sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fqHDq2McgP_mOh7iXxiE6otzbGDebjyi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, I chose `-tint` for the filter to only affect mid-tones. If you want the whites affected too, replace `-tint` with `-colorize`